# How do I pass the region information as environment variable to a container running in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a use case where I publish messages from containers deployed in various regions and I would like to tag those messages from the region they originated from. Also, I want to do this in a container engine agnostic way so specifically want to access the region info as an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose pod information as an environment variable using the [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api)

However, this isn't supported for node labels, as per [these](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52000) [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40610) [issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/25957).

What you can do is follow [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api) and labels your pods/deployments (and also maybe pin those pods/deployments using a [NodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector)) and then expose that info. An example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
  labels:
    zone: us-west-2
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c", $(ZONE)]
      env:
        - name: ZONE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.labels.zone
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Please note, I haven't tested this so YMMV